# How to refresh environment variables after outside editing without re-running the process

Tags: command-line, process, cmd, refresh, environment-variables

The environment variables are cached when a process starts.
Assume I start CommandPrompt with the current set of environment variables (and their values).
Then I change OUTSIDE (by System properties window) some values of these environment variables or even add some new.

When I type now `echo %var1%` then the old value of environment variable is visible.

How can I "refresh" the environment variables inside this CommandPrompt from the current (updated) state without re-running the process?

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done the way you describe it, unless you type the changes into the console window using `sendkeys` or `AutoIt` - but I presume the cmd window will be running some executable.